# Spring boot STOMP websocket works locally, but not on deployed server

Tags: spring, websocket, deployment, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a STOMP client and Spring backend, the code works fine when local but not when deployed to server, failed to connect to server.

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/tracker").setAllowedOrigins("*");
}
```

}

Javascript client initiates connection with :
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/tracker");

When I try this after deployment

> WebSocket("wss://myurl/tracker")

or

> WebSocket("wss://myurl:8080/tracker")

The connection fails

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details? What is the exact error code and message?

Is it possible that you have a reverse proxy or a load balancer in front of your deployment server? This could be blocking the websocket from connecting in the deployment environment. In that case, you need to configure the proxy/balancer to allow for websockets. In NGINX, these are the lines you are looking for:

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
```

Websocket connection starts with an HTTP Upgrade request to upgrade the protocol to WS or WSS depending on security. The lines above instruct NGINX to pass that request further to the server.

I recommend you have an in-depth read here in [NGINS's guide.](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)